# TLS 1.3 not working on Nginx 1.17.6 / Ubuntu 18.04 / OpenSSL 1.1.1

Tags: ssl, nginx, openssl, ubuntu-18.04, tls1.3

I'm hosting at Digital Ocean with Ubuntu 18.04, Nginx version 1.17.6, OpenSSL version 1.1.1 . - I believe those satisfy requirements for TLS 1.3.

In my **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf** file I added TLSv1.3 like so:
`ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;`

I have not changed anything in **/etc/nginx/sites-available/website.com** .

When I test my site in SSL Labs and elsewhere, TLSv1.3 is not working. It's still using TLSv1.2.

I checked `nginx -V`, and `--with-openSSL` argument is not listed. Not sure if I have to rebuild my nginx with that flag.

Any pointers would be appreciated

**UPDATE:**
I rebuilt Nginx from source with OpenSSL 1.1.1. Still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution after much digging. I had to update **/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf** and add `ssl protocols TLSv1.3` there, as well as add to `ssl_ciphers` TLS 1.3 ciphers `TLS-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256:TLS-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:`

Comment: can you provide the full SSL ciphers which you used and can you please provide the doc where you referred? I am also doing the same thing you did but no changes

Comment: @jayaprakashR I'm afraid this was so long ago that I've forgotten most of what I did... so can't really help you beyound what's already mentioned here.

Comment: What I do see for a site where I have a working TLSv1.3, is this config in my nginx.conf:

```ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;```